# Search a table with comma delimited string?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column in my table called tags. It has comma delimited text in it (box, hat, car).

I select a row from my table and I want to find other rows that have similar tags to the tags in the row selected.

I know it could be a better table design, but I can't change the design.

I know this will search the tags for a keyword, but I don't want to search via a keyword but by a list of tags.

```
WHERE (',' + Tags + ',') LIKE '%,keyword,%'
```

Does anyone know how I would do this?

Using MYSQL.

Comment: You shouldn't be storing comma separated values in the first place.

Comment: it won't work.. even if you have the tags ordered alphabetically, then you could find `a,b,c,d` when looking for `b,c`, but certainly you wont find `a,b,c,d` looking for `b,d`, unless you split the tags and compare one by one, which would be very inefficient

Comment: you can store this by serialize() is there any problem which that

Comment: Michael: how about LIKE b,%d,

Comment: Pleas read [SQL antipatterns](http://pragprog.com/book/bksqla/sql-antipatterns). Chapter 1: Jaywalking.

Comment: "i know it could be a better table design, but I can't change the design."

Comment: Your keyword example won't always work anyway unless the comma delimited string begins/ends with a comma.

Comment: Great comment from teresko. +1

Comment: @JaredCostall can you add to the schema? even a trigger that maintained an independent 1-value:1-column table would probably be better in the long run. Otherwise FIND_IN_SET() can match a delimited token.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say you can't change the design.  Can you add a FULLTEXT index and put this table in the MyISAM access method?  If so you can use FULLTEXT searching. For your application you'll do best using BOOLEAN mode.

```
WHERE MATCH (tags)
      AGAINST ('box hat -car' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

This particular search looks for keywords box and hat, and excludes the keyword car.

Here's a description.  This might work well for you. 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html

You can run a FULLTEXT search in InnoDB. But I don't believe you can index it.

If you can't use a fulltext search, you're stuck with the wrong tool for your job.  Matching comma-delimited strings with SQL is like driving nails by hitting them with the handle of a screwdriver. Both take a long time and are incredibly awkward.